# Displaying and updating table thats boxed in a class in my view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im having issues getting data to appear in a datagrid in my view.

```
public class ComputerViewModel: ObservableObject
{

    private ObservableCollection<ComputerModel> _ComputerInformation;
    public ObservableCollection<ComputerModel> ComputerInformation {
        get { return _ComputerInformation; }
        set {
            _ComputerInformation = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ComputerInformation");
        }
    }
    public ComputerViewModel()
    {
        ComputerInformation = new ObservableCollection<ComputerModel>();
        ComputerModel computer = new ComputerModel();
        computer.start("DA2968");
        ComputerInformation.Add(computer);
    }
}

public class ComputerModel: ObservableObject
{
     private DataTable _ProcessHistory;
     public DataTable ProcessHistory {
         get { return _ProcessHistory; }
         set { _ProcessHistory = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ProcessHistory"); }
     }
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Source=ComputerInformation}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessHistory}"/>
```

im not sure its even possible.
Basically i have code that monitors process creation and deletion on multiple computers.
I intitate a new model for each computer and would like to store them in the ViewModel.
which is working fine. im just having difficulty showing the information on the screen. can anyone please help.

ObservableObject is where my INotifyPropertyChanged and DelegateCommand is located.
ComputerModel is where the code for monitoring the creation and deletion of process is located. this is all working fine and storing in the DataTable fine. the data is there i just cannot display it.

Thanks

Comment: the datagrid need to know which ComputerInformation the processhistories need to be displayed from, are you trying to show all the processhistory regardless of the computerinformation?

Comment: I see what you mean. so i need to somehow indicate to the datagrid which index to look at. im not sure how i could do this from binding. The user clicks on a Computername in a ListView and the data needs to be loaded into the datagrid.

Comment: ahh then just bind the datagrid datacontext to the selectedvalue of the listview

Comment: just for  testing i attempted this  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ComputerInformation[0].ProcessHistory}"/> and got no where. i think the issue is that the data in the datatable is constantly updating.

Comment: have u set the datacontext to the viewmodel?, try using a dummy data if you want to test, i tried it using dummy data and it works

Comment: Yeah thats done here this.DataContext = new ComputerViewModel(); not sure whats going on here.

Comment: Alright got it to work. i think i must have mis spelled something, did the joyus copy and paste of all the variables and it seems to be working. but yeah its that [0] pointer i was missing in the first place. thanks for your assistance.